# Powershell script for copying dlls and pdbs name working but not erroring out

Tags: powershell, dll, pdb-files

The below script doesn't error out and it doesn't work.  I have trapped it inside of a try catch block and that isn't working either.  I am attempting to move only pdb, and dll files to a certain folder.  However, when I run this script, the dll's and pdb's aren't moved.  I probably have an order of operations mixup or something, but I thought this script should have worked...

```
gci -path $FromPath -Include ("*.dll", "*.pdp") | ? {$_.Name -match "PackageServiceLib|Package.capture.CSE.inc|PackageDBCore|Package.capture|PackageCommon|PackageServiceFramework"} | Copy-item -path $FromPath -destination $ToPath -force
```

Comment: Any time you're dealing with a complex issue like this, scale things back and build it one step at a time. Start with the `Get-ChildItem` command, and make sure it's returning the data you're expecting, then move onto the `Where-Object` filter, and so on.

Comment: Good point.  I thought I broke down everything pretty well.  Obviously though I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your `$FromPath` variable doesn't specify `\*` at the end. If you don't specify that, then your `-Include` parameter will be useless.

Assuming that a folder named `c:\test` contains 10 files with a `.txt` file extension, consider the difference between this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test -Include *.txt;
```

And this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\* -Include *.txt;
```

The first command will yield no output, because you are getting the directory, not the **children** of the directory. In the second command, we are specifying that we want everything that is a child of the directory, **except** we only want the items that match the `-Include` parameter.

Comment: Seems like I am getting back objects now, But i am getting an exception:  Copy-Item:  The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the the command either...'

Comment: looks like I need a foreach loop in this

Comment: I believe you should be able to avoid using a foreach loop, since `Copy-Item` is aware of the pipeline objects. For example: `gci c:\windows\windowsupdate.log | copy-item -dest c:\test`

Comment: Dagnabbit, that cleared up the error, but nothing is being coppied... I can't figure this thing out?

Comment: will that command copy files to a path that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: You'll have to create the folder first, using `mkdir`.